# LibreCalc Search and Replace, Search for [] and replace it, along with its contents

Tags: regex, search, replace, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I am compiling a list of video games. 
At this time, I am currently using Wikipedia to do so.
As I copied ps3 games over to LibreCalc, the copied titles of the video games include citation brackets at the end of the line. Rather than remove this line by, I am trying to search and replace the brackets and their contents.

I continue to fail in this endeavor.  An example below,

```
Rune Factory: Tides of Destiny[629]
Fight Night Champion[268]
Dragon Age II[209]
Major League Baseball 2K11[427]
MLB 11: The Show[459]
Warriors: Legends of Troy[817]
Dynasty Warriors 7[222]
Homefront[334]
Top Spin 4[773]
MotorStorm: Apocalypse[474]
Crysis 2[164]
Lego Star Wars III: The Clone Wars
The Tomb Raider Trilogy[765]
NASCAR 2011: The Game[488]
Shift 2: Unleashed[650]
Tiger Woods PGA Tour 12: The Masters[746]
WWE All Stars[839]
Michael Jackson: The Experience[448]
Rio[614]
Mortal Kombat[469]
Portal 2[563]
SOCOM 4: U.S. Navy SEALs[20]
AFL Live[16]
Operation Flashpoint: Red River[542]
Man vs. Wild[430]
Sniper: Ghost Warrior[679]
El Shaddai: Ascension of the Metatron[233]
Virtua Tennis 4[808]
Thor: God of Thunder[740]
MX vs. ATV Alive[478]
Brink[116]
Lego Pirates of the Caribbean: The Video Game[391]
Battle vs. Chess[82]
L.A. Noire[379]
Dirt 3[196]
Kung Fu Panda 2[377]
Hunted: The Demon's Forge[336]
Infamous 2[345]
Red Faction: Armageddon[599]
Yakuza: Dead Souls[849]
Duke Nukem Forever[217]
Alice: Madness Returns[29]
Child of Eden[146]
Transformers: Dark of the Moon[777]
Dungeon Siege III[218]
Cars 2: The Video Game[138]
F.E.A.R. 3[247]
Shadows of the Damned[647]
Atelier Meruru: The Apprentice of Arland[67]
Bleach: Soul Resurrección[108]
Angel Love Online[38]
Angel Senki
Air Conflicts: Secret Wars[24]
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part II[322]
NCAA Football 12[511]
Captain America: Super Soldier[137]
Call of Juarez: The Cartel[136]
Phineas and Ferb: Across the 2nd Dimension[558]
Hyperdimension Neptunia Mk2[338]
Deus Ex: Human Revolution[191]
Bodycount[111]
Madden NFL 12[415]
Driver: San Francisco[216]
Dead Island[175]
Resistance 3[609]
Warhammer 40000: Space Marine[815]
NHL 12[526]
Tales of Xillia[718]
God of War: Origins Collection[298]
Tom Clancy's Splinter Cell Classic Trilogy HD[762]
Supremacy MMA[712]
Dark Souls[169]
Ico & Shadow of the Colossus Collection[340]
FIFA 12[263]
PES 2012: Pro Evolution Soccer[557]
Dynasty Warriors 7: Xtreme Legends[223]
Ra.One: The Game[584]
Crysis[163]
Rage[586]
Spider-Man: Edge of Time[692]
NBA 2K12[498]
The Cursed Crusade[733]
Ace Combat: Assault Horizon[12]
Skylanders: Spyro's Adventure[675]
Batman: Arkham City[79]
Ratchet & Clank: All 4 One[591]
Rocksmith[627]
The Sims 3: Pets[658]
The Adventures of Tintin: The Secret of the Unicorn[14]
Back to the Future: The Game[71]
Battlefield 3[83]
Dragon Ball Z: Ultimate Tenkaichi[212]
Puss in Boots[581]
The Idolmaster 2[736]
Uncharted 3: Drake's Deception[795]
GoldenEye 007: Reloaded[301]
The Lord of the Rings: War in the North[401]
Sonic Generations[683]
Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3[131]
Metal Gear Solid HD Collection[445]
The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim[236]
Lego Harry Potter: Years 5–7[388]
Assassin's Creed: Revelations[63]
Jurassic Park: The Game[358]
Cartoon Network: Punch Time Explosion XL[141]
Need for Speed: The Run[516]
Saints Row: The Third[633]
Apache: Air Assault[42]
After Hours Athletes[21]
Ni no Kuni[531]
WWE '12[838]
The King of Fighters XIII[371]
Just Dance 3[361]
Order Up![543]
Final Fantasy XIII-2[273]
Zack Zero[853]
Armored Core V[52]
NeverDead[520]
Soulcalibur V[689]
Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning[374]
The Darkness II[735]
Grand Slam Tennis 2[306]
Twisted Metal[787]
UFC Undisputed 3[792]
Binary Domain[95]
Asura's Wrath[64]
Syndicate[714]
Gal*Gun[288]
Naruto Shippuden: Ultimate Ninja Storm Generations[485]
SSX[698]
One Piece: Pirate Warriors[539][540]
Blades of Time[101]
Major League Baseball 2K12[428]
Mass Effect 3[436]
MLB 12: The Show[460]
Street Fighter X Tekken[706]
Top Gun: Hard Lock[771]
Mobile Suit Gundam Unicorn[465]
FIFA Street[265]
Silent Hill: Downpour[653]
Silent Hill HD Collection[654]
Ninja Gaiden 3[535]
Resident Evil: Operation Raccoon City[605]
Ridge Racer Unbounded[613]
Battleship[87]
Prototype 2[577]
Max Payne 3[438]
Dragon's Dogma[214]
Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon: Future Soldier[756]
Dirt: Showdown[197]
Inversion[350]
Tokyo Jungle[753]
```

Part of my problem seems to be that brackets are characters used in regular expressions.

Can some one assist me, or toss me in the right direction to solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [escape the brackets with a backslash](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer#Special_characters) so they are treated as regular characters. On that base, you could use the following regex to match all square brackets [containing only digits](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer#POSIX_bracket_expressions_.5B%3aalpha%3a.5D_.5B%3adigit%3a.5D_etc..):

> `\[[:digit:]*\]`

When leaving the `Replace with` box empty, a search/replace run should remove all footnote marks in your example.

Since only the opening bracket is a special character for LO Calc, the following should work, too:

> `\[[:digit:]*]`